# Можете объяснить смысл задачи?

Tags: c++

Ильнар в одной из комнат увидел странного робота. Во время выполнения алгоритма, он доставал из мешка разные камушки. Причем он никогда не доставал один и тот же камень два раза. И говорил сколько камушков в мешке такого же цвета.

Разработчик робота рассказал Ильнару, что из-за ошибки в коде робот ровно один раз всегда ошибается.

Теперь Ильнару интересно, а сколько минимально может быть камушков в мешке. Формат входных данных

В первой строке содержится единственное целое число n (1≤n≤105) — количество выбранных камушков.

Во второй строке находятся n целых чисел ai (1≤ai≤109) — значения, названные роботом. Формат выходных данных

Выведите одно положительное целое число — минимальное возможное количество камушков в мешке.

Sample Input:

4

2 2 2 2

Sample Output:

5

Comment: Надо попросить Ильнара отобрать мешок с камнями и пересчитать :)

Comment: 1) написано что он доставал камушки из мешка, но не написано  ложил ли он их назад? 2) камушки нумерованые? 3) Какое количество цветов имеется? 4)Что значит "ошибается" один раз. Это ошибка в количестве камушков такого же цвета или он ошибочно достает тот же камушек? 5)Каждый раз разные - разные по цвету или по номеру?

Comment: @V.March: 1) Условие "никогда не доставал один и тот же камень два раза" неявно говорит о том, что камешки кладутся назад. 2) Условие "никогда не доставал один и тот же камень два раза" очевидно говорит о том, что все камушки уникальны/отличимы, т.е. условно "нумерованы". 3) Количество цветов не ограничено. Требование минимизации в вопросе задачи естественным образом "ограничивает" количество цветов. 4) Резонный вопрос. (Ясно, что речь идет об ошибке в количестве, но тем не менее...) 5) *Разные камни* - это именно *разные камни*, т.е. разные именно по условному уникальному "номеру".

Comment: Я пологаю, что хитрость в том, что робот может вытащить разные камушки одного цвета. Например вытащить три разных камушка, и сказать кол-во камушков 10, 10, 10. Если камушки разного цвета, то их минимум 30, если одинакового, то минимум 10.

Comment: @e.n.shirokov Так вот, На мой взгляд, первое число (из примера), это колличество найденых роботом камушков разных цветов. а следующая строка, это колличество камушков каждого отдельного цвета.. 
Вся проблема здесь с ошибкой... Что значит ошибка, как ее располагать.. Это совершенно не ясно
Вот код, который у меня получился

Comment: #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    int s = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        s = s + arr[i]-1;
    }
    s = s + 1;
    cout << s;
    return 0;
    
}
Но этот код не правильный.. Так и идеи кончились на этом..

Comment: @V.March Все что указано в задаче, я все предоставил...

Comment: @tebenkov2222 А Вы случайно не задавали такой же вопрос с меткой PYTHON? Вчера в это же время.

Comment: @V.March
Нет. Это не я.. Видел этот вопрос.. К сожалению я phyton не знаю..
У меня ник везде tebenkov2222, не перепутаете

Comment: Значит совпадение, или кроме Вас еще и python-дэв в ту же компанию пробует на работу устроиться. И ему такое же задание дали.

Comment: @V.March
У меня олимпиада.. И у того человека видать тоже...